# How can similar columns be added to all entities without using embedded entity in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

If I want to add similar columns to all my entities in TypeORM, for example, each entity should have a `CreatedDate` and an `UpdatedDate` column in their respected database table and entity, using TypeORM's built in `@CreateDateColumn` and `@UpdatedDateColumn` decorators.  I can achieve this by creating an embedded entity, and it works as expected, but when I query it and it returns its JSON format, the embedded entity is a sub-object.  Is there a way to either flatten that sub-object in the JSON, or add these columns to all entities another way?  I also used inheritance but I want these particular columns to show up as the last columns in the table/entity.  When using inheritance they show up first.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use composition for that, you can use inheritance with an abstract class.

```
export abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @CreatedDateColumn()
    createdDate: Date;
}

@Entity()
export class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    // Some code
}
```